# What is a solution of "Multiple ResultSets were returned by the query"

Tags: java, postgresql, resultset

I get error:

```
ERROR [NewsDAO] findAll(): org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Multiple ResultSets were returned by the query.
```

Im using postgresql-8.4-703.jdbc4.jar.

My code looks like:

```
private static StringBuilder findAllQuery = new StringBuilder();

    {
    findAllQuery.append("SELECT * FROM news;");
}

    public List<News> findAll() {
    Statement stm = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    List<News> results = new ArrayList<News>();
    if (obtainConnection()) {
        try {
            stm = con.createStatement();
            rs = stm.executeQuery(findAllQuery.toString());
            while(rs.next())
                results.add(setInObject(rs));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("findAll(): " + e);
        } finally {
            logger.info("Zamknalem");
            closeConnection();
        }
    }
    return results;
}
    public News setInObject(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    News news = new News();
    news.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
    news.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));
    news.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
    //TODO: timestamp
    news.setDate(rs.getDate("date"));
    User user = new User();
    user.setId(rs.getInt("user_id"));
    news.setUser(user);
    news.setActive(rs.getBoolean("active"));
    return news;
}
```

I don't know why i get this error. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code where you actually create/assign `findAllQuery`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You must have [multiple select statements](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-jdbc/2007-05/msg00053.php) in `findAllQuery.toString()`.

***Edit***

As JB Nizet pointed out, you should try removing the semicolon from the statement.  The Postgresql JDBC driver splits statements on the semicolon, so it may be issuing two statements.

Comment: @TomaszGutkowski: Remove the semicolon at the end of the query.

Comment: Tim Pote your comment brought me to the solution of my problem. Problem was here: private **static** StringBuilder findAllQuery = new StringBuilder();

Comment: In my case, the final semicolon wasn't the problem _per se_, but it was that I had COMMENTS after the semicolon:

`AND this.that = 'bliggity blag';  -- important comment`